# LocoTranslate не переводит нужную строку

Tags: wordpress

У становил LocoTranslate, тема подготовлена под перевод ( название темы - "crestyler". В *functions.php* есть строка:

```
load_theme_textdomain( 'crestyler', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );
```

Мне надо перевод слово "All" в фильтре портфолио. Строка, где прописано слово имеет вид:

```
$term_list .= '<a href="#filter" data-option-value="*" data-catname="all" data-title="' . $query_for_count_all_terms->post_count . '">' . esc_html__('All', 'crestyler') . '</a>
```

В админке, в LocoTranslate находит это слово и я перевел на "Все", но вот в фронте это никак не отобразилось... 
Вроде все нормально и должно сработать, но что-то не срабатывает. Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать хук gettext

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/gettext/

Comment: Спасибо. Но можно-ли как-то настроить сам Loco, что-б он видел это слово ( думал, что , может, я в настройках плагина что-то не учел. Папка, куда сохраняются переводы - есть - путь верный...